# Gmail converting image to empty image

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, actionmailer

I have a strange problem, My Images are getting converted to empty image when I am sending an email through the action mailer.

Same images are getting displayed in yandex email.

YANDEX

```
<img width="180" height="60" style="margin-left:20px;" alt="Logo" src="https://resize.yandex.net/mailservice?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fimages%2Flogo.png&amp;width=0&amp;height=0&amp;key=fe215a359fd5542edc16d12e3c3a5eeb">
```

I dont understand what is happening with GMAIL, image links are forming like this.

```
<img width="180" height="60" style="margin-left:20px" src="" alt="Logo" class="CToWUd">
```

So it is not showing images. Am I missing something.

Thanks

Comment: for test purpose could you please use this src `http://resize.yandex.net/0_ac5dd_d5908964_M?url=http%3A%2F%2Fimg-fotki.yandex.ru%2Fget%2F6728%2F63430198.76f%2F0_ac5dd_d5908964_M&width=222&height=0&typemap=gif%3Agif%3Bpng%3Apng%3B*%3Ajpeg%3B&timestamp=1381400884&crop=no&enlarge=no&key=b7eaf8565de9c6b2b4eab5e3e5971913`

Comment: @rony36, I used this src and its showing me the image in gmail as well. I guess somehow gmail is removing the src attribute completely, I did it thorough developer tool

Comment: One last try. Use this code: https://gist.github.com/mur-wtag/63d653d9cb60828c957c

Answer (score 0):

> Encode your image/binary file into Base64 hash

You can try this [tool](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64).
And prepare your code like this:

```
<img width="180" height="60" style="margin-left:20px;" alt="Logo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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%3D"/>
```

Thanks!